# Ajax geolocation how to show error if person refuses to give location

Tags: jquery, ajax, geolocation

If a person accepts the request to show their location it works.  But if I try and detect if the user refused I get nothing.  I'd like to post if the person refused, so I have a record.  This is the code it doesn't show any errors if I refuse to give my location I thought the error: function() would work??

```
function getCoordPosition() { 

if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
 function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{path('login_log_location')}}",
        data: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        },
    success: function () {
   $("#divputinarea").html('<form method=post action="path('login_log_yourarea')}}">   
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Find your nearest matches</button>');
        },
   error: function () { 
   $("#divputinarea").html('got error'); 
            }
     });
});
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)` has also `error` function which has `PositionError` parameter. That one can be used to retrieve information. For example

```
function getCoordPosition() { 

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{path('login_log_location')}}",
                data: {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                },
                success: function () {
                    // ****
                    $("#divputinarea").html('<form method=post action="path(' + login_log_yourarea + ')}}"> <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Find your nearest matches</button>');
                },
                error: function () { 
                    $("#divputinarea").html('got error'); 
                }
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('failed: ');
            console.log(error);
            if (error.code == 1) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // do something!
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

Error object written into console:

```
PositionError {message: "User denied Geolocation", code: 1, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3…}
```

So `error.message` is `User denied Geolocation`. See also [MDN Posiiton Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError) for explanation. Code value 1 is `PERMISSION_DENIED`: *The acquisition of the geolocation information failed because the page didn't have the permission to do it.*

**Note:** check also line after comment with "****". I'm not sure if that line is correct. There are two `}}`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit my code to include your changes, I get an error or it doesn't work.  Can you show me the complete code please